# I need help joining tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need help on joining these three fields,

Party table where all party information stored:  it just a list of Party Name and ID. and it look like this

```
PartyID PartyName
14      CIDS
15      DTL
16      CRTS
17      VIVAR
18      CT INC
19      AMC INC
20      YIBG
38      LLA INC
35      GFRC
43      UC AM    
44     CIDW
46       KIN TECH
47      MAIN RP
85      CCDS
```

I have this Responsible Party table as

```
  RPID  PID PartyID
   38   42   85
```

I have this subparty table

```
SPID    RPID PartyID
14      38    43
15      38    44
16      38    45
17      38    45
18      38    46
19      38    47
20      38    47
```

I need your help on displaying  my data as

```
RPID    PartyID  PartyName  SubID   SubParty
38       43      UCAM       14      CIDS    
38       44      CIDW       15      DTL
38       45                 16      CRTS
38       45                 17      VIVAR   
38       46    KIN TECH     18     CT INC
38       47                 20      YIBG
38       85     CCDS
```

Comment: In your expected results there is no partyname for pertyid = 47. Why? Also in the subparty table there are 2 rows with partyid = 47/

Comment: "I have"/"I need" is nice, but some sort of explanation of how to get from the sample data to the desired results would be helpful. Showing what you've tried also helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `subparty` to `responsibleparty` and 2 copies of `party`:

```
select sp.rpid, sp.partyid, p.partyname, sp.spid, pp.partyname subparty
from subparty sp
left join responsibleparty rp on rp.rpid = sp.rpid
left join party p on p.partyid = sp.partyid
left join party pp on pp.partyid = sp.spid
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f574a95df4ca14227d2237ef38d695c4).
Results:

```
> rpid | partyid | partyname | spid | subparty
> ---: | ------: | :-------- | ---: | :-------
>   38 |      43 | UC AM     |   14 | CIDS    
>   38 |      44 | CIDW      |   15 | DTL     
>   38 |      45 | null      |   16 | CRTS    
>   38 |      45 | null      |   17 | VIVAR   
>   38 |      46 | KIN TECH  |   18 | CT INC  
>   38 |      47 | MAIN RP   |   19 | AMC INC 
>   38 |      47 | MAIN RP   |   20 | YIBG
```

Comment: thank you! how can i add rp.PartyName to PartyName field?

Comment: `rp` is the alias of the table `responsibleparty`. There is no column `PartyName` in that table.

Comment: Ah im so sorry my bad i forgot to add PartyID, i have PartyID field can you help me add rps PartyName and merge with the PartyName field in your answer :)? Thaank you the help

Comment: Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a71d78f9cc2a9f523ddad2052247a902

Comment: Thanks Can we add CCDS's info or rp.partyname info as a separate row?

Comment: Row or column?.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6e12091e4ec2a429421b74748bfe9f1a

Comment: Is there anyway to get ride of the duplicate?

Comment: There are no duplicates. Every row is different.

Comment: i removed `left join party p on p.partyid = sp.partyid
left join party pp on pp.partyid = sp.spid` and replace these two with null `sp.spid, pp.partyname subparty`   it seems like it working for me, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT ResponsibleParty.RPID
    ,subParty.PartyKey AS PartyID
    ,party.PartyName
    ,PartyTable.PartyID AS SubID
    ,subPartyName.PartyName AS SubParty
FROM ResponsibleParty
INNER JOIN PartyTable ON ResponsibleParty.SPID = PartyTable.PartyID
INNER JOIN ResponsibleParty subParty ON subParty.SPID = PartyTable.PartyID
LEFT JOIN PartyTable party ON subparty.PartyKey = party.PartyID
LEFT JOIN PartyTable subPartyName ON ResponsibleParty.SPID = subPartyName.PartyID
```

Here is the live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf9efe46ab70ba621106bcb3a8c2af81) demo.